# I would like to know if an ultrasonic sensor array will be able to mimic the laser range sensor required for the navigation stack provided by ROS

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I Have 3 Ultrasonic Sensors and motor Encoders for Odometry. I am planning on using the ROS navigation stack in order to help me produce a 2D floor map, will this be possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211715/i-would-like-to-know-if-an-ultrasonic-sensor-array-(3-sensors,-45-degrees-apart)-will-be-able-to-mimic-the-laser-range-sensor-required-for-the-navigation-stack-provided-by-ros./) by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [range_sensor_layer](http://wiki.ros.org/range_sensor_layer) in Hydro and mroe recent version of ROS navigation to incorporate the Range datatype, but you will get a lot less data (and degraded performance) using sonar.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-06-22**:
I have been looking into this, and the navigation stack requires sensor streams to be published to the stack, currently it says that the stack only supports laser_scan and Point  Cloud messages. How do I interpret the sensor_msgs/Range in order to use the stack?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-22**:
Where does it say that? That's probably some outdated documentation.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-06-22**:
http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Sensors: "However, the current navigation stack only accepts sensor data published using either the sensor_msgs/LaserScan Message type or the sensor_msgs/PointCloud Message type"

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-22**:
Thanks. Using the range_sensor_layer gets around that requirement. http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-06-22**:
Okay I will do. Thanks for the help!

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-06-30**:
I have a question regarding the range_sensor_layer, if you have more than one sensor is there more than one plugin for the yaml file, ie.- {name: sonar1,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
then the next one would be sonar2?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-30**:
Yes. you can name it whatever is convenient.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-07**:
Hi @David, How to I use AMCL, can I just remap my ultrasonic sensors to the /scan topic? If so how do I do it?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-07-07**:
I don't know what you're asking.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-08**:
Sorry, I have set-up the navigation stack with the tutorial on the navigation stack [Robot_setup](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/%22Navigation_stack%22). So I want to  use AMCL to localize my robot. How can I use AMCL because it expects a laserscan  to the topic /scan.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-08**:
and im using the range_sensor_layer for three sonar sensors.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-08**:
Shall I maybe post a new question?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-07-08**:
Yeah, this has ventured into new question territory.

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-07-08**:
Ok I have asked the question: here is the link [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/213139/using-amcl-for-navigation-with-navigation-stack-std_msgsrange-range_sensor-layer/%22question%22)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably not. At least not in the same way. You can publish this as laser messages, but you have 3 (noisy) beams instead of at least 180 beams from a laser. I doubt that the laser-based algorithms will work well with that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1